# How can make this chart mechanics work in my application

Tags: javascript, charts

Thats main goals of this task:

1. chart needs to be displayed when currenct account is set ( when user is logged in )
2. then chart need to update it self when new transaction is added
3. new transaction must be displayed on chart with the amount of transaction and date of it.

i have already create workable version it, but only when i set current account by myself not when it is depended upon what user was logged in. i cant find a solution to properly use exports with this chart to be displayed on init function(init function is when certain user is logged to app)

```
export const initSettings = function (currentAccount) {
  currentUser.displayTransactionsOverview(currentAccount);
  currentUser.displayTransactionsTransaction(currentAccount);
  currentUser.displayCardDetails(currentAccount);
  transactions.transactions(currentAccount);
  profile.profileSettings(currentAccount);
  updateBalance(currentAccount);
```

in that function should be something like :
`chart.displayChart(currentAccount)`

and on updateUI function:

```
export const updateUI = function (currentAccount) {
  currentUser.displayTransactionsOverview(currentAccount);
  currentUser.displayTransactionsTransaction(currentAccount);
```

in that function should be something like :
`chart.destroyChart(); chart.renderChart();`

so when i set current user in that update.js module whitch is simple becouse i use no exports there i have something like that:

```
let dataArr = [];
let labelsArr = [];

currentAccount.transactions.forEach((t) => {
  const dateReady = currentUser.dateCreator(t.date);
  labelsArr.push(dateReady);
  dataArr.push(t.amount);
});

// setup chart block
const data = {
  labels: labelsArr,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: dataArr,
      label: "# of Amount",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#01a001",
      backgroundColor: "#01a001",
    },
  ],
};

// config block
const config = {
  type: "line",
  data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: false,
      },
    },
  },
};

// init block
let chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);

// destroy chart
export let destroyChart = function () {
  chart.destroy();
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
  chart.data.labels = [];
  labelsArr = [];
  dataArr = [];
};


// render chart again
let renderChart = function () {
  chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);

  currentAccount.transactions.forEach((t) => {
    const dateReady = currentUser.dateCreator(t.date);
    labelsArr.push(dateReady);

    dataArr.push(t.amount);
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = dataArr;
    chart.data.labels = labelsArr;
    chart.update();
  });
};
```

the problem is that i cant make this work without declaring currentaccount there by my self like:

```
let currentAccount;

currentAccount = acc.accounts.find((acc) => acc.userName === "tom123");
```

and it works how it should, expect i dont want to have this code in update.js module, id rather put it in chart.js module but then i dont have access to current account there.
i cant find a solution with exporting that. and also export nested in export dont work so i am in the middle of nowhere here.

so my question is how can i make this work. i hope that my question is somewhat understandable

i i tried exporting it but it doesnt seem to work becouse when i select chart.data ...etc it says it is undefined